# Regex in nodejs native module

Tags: c++, regex, node.js, parsing, native

I'm writing a C++ module for nodejs for a heavy data parsing. I decided to write the parsing in c++, because it will be faster. My goal is to do something like this:

```
preg_match_all("@(==[^=]+==)(.+?(?=[^=]==[^=]|$))@s", $source, $paragraphs);
$data = preg_replace("/\[\[(Файл|Картинка|File|Picture|Image|double image):(.*)/i", "", $source);
```

but in c++.. I did a research and I found the Boost lib, but I couldn't install it on VisualStudio.. My goal is to implement the regexs showed above in the following c++ code:

```
#include <node.h>

using namespace v8;

Handle<Value> Callback(const Arguments& args) {
HandleScope scope;

if (!args[1]->IsFunction()) {
    return ThrowException(Exception::TypeError(
        String::New("Second argument must be a callback function")));
}

Local<Function> callback = Local<Function>::Cast(args[1]);

Local<String> text = args[0]->ToString();

// do regexs and data parsing here

const unsigned argc = 2;
Local<Value> argv[argc] = {
    Local<Value>::New(Null()),
    //, JSON OUTPUT HERE
};

callback->Call(Context::GetCurrent()->Global(), argc, argv);

return Undefined();
}

void RegisterModule(Handle<Object> target) {
target->Set(String::NewSymbol("parse"), FunctionTemplate::New(Callback)->GetFunction());
}

NODE_MODULE(wikiparser, RegisterModule);
```

**Problems:**

Any suggestions how I can use such functions in c++, or any easy way to accomplish my goal? Note, that there won't be just 1-2 regexes - there will be like 10-15.

Comment: here's c++'s [regex library](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex) but I can tell you right now if your used to scripting languages regexes you will find c++'s very clunky and hard to use

Comment: There is one site where you can try your luck to get the Boost installer for Visual C++. They have closed the support but older versions are still available in case you want to give this a try.
http://www.boostpro.com/download/

Comment: If your are not at least an intermediate C++ programmer, don't expect your code will be any faster than the JS version in any considerable time. Also take the portability issue of nodejs addons into account.